# IE10 doesn't parse JSON properly

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I've reduced the problem to its bare bones using JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZuV7J/

This properly parses the simple JSON string in Firefox and Chrome, but returns an empty object (regardless of the JSON string used) in IE8, IE9 and IE10. I'm yet to try with IE11.

This happens whether or not I load Crockford's JSON2.js library.

Comment: What happens if you make the variable local, i.e. use `var event ...` instead? Also, which expression exactly produces an empty object? Are you saying that `alert(event.var)` prints an empty object? That's highly unlikely.

Comment: It works in the developer tools' console for IE9 and 10, but you're right, when the page loads on that Fiddle, it shows undefined.

Comment: In the developer's console it just shows {} for me! Just tested with IE11 and got the same result.

Comment: That's odd... I even copied the code to a local script, and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Nicolas: You mean that `console.log(JSON.stringify(event));` shows an empty object? That's not parsing then, that's converting an object *to* JSON (stringifying)! Please clarify your question.

Comment: The problem isn't that it can't parse the JSON correctly, it's that there is already a native event object bound to 'event' that it won't let you overwrite

Comment: @FelixKling, I'm reconverting it to a JSON string because IE's console doesn't dump object members like FF or Chrome. If the JSON string is correctly parsed, it should be re-serialised to its original form without problem.

Comment: That's what you assumed, but as you know now, IE parsed the value correctly.

Comment: @FelixKling I actually owe this one to you, since you initially suggested declaring it with var. Kudos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Internet Explorer `window.event`

> Represents the state of an event, such as the element in which the
>   event occurred, the state of the keyboard keys, the location of the
>   mouse, and the state of the mouse buttons.

It cannot be assigned to.

Without `var`, your code `event = JSON.parse('{"var":"value"}');` tries to assign to `window.event` which is not allowed.

Change to use a different variable name or prefix event with var so your code reads: `var event=JSON.parse('{"var":"value"}');`

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZuV7J/1/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Don't use the variable name "event" without declaring it locally with var :-)